# Como posso fazer um select e transforma-lo em array

Tags: php

Bom, pelo titulo da pergunta não consegui explicar muito bem o que queria mas aqui vai na prática:

Eu tenho um select a uma tabela designada por "postos".

Este select quer que me indique todos os postos, onde o supervisor é o "Teste".

Depois disso faço um mysqli_fetch_array

E de seguida mostro o $array["posto"];

Contudo, só me mostra 1 posto, e na verdade o supervisor "Teste", tem mais que um posto.

Como posso transformar os postos do select em 1 array?

Obrigado.

Comment: Já percebi que tem q ser com while. contudo pretendo transformar o valor em array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Gonçalo, tomei por base a [resposta do Gonçalo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/179117/70) mas simplifiquei o loop:

```
$postos = array();
while($array1 = mysqli_fetch_array($procura1)) $postos[] = $array1['posto'];
```

Isto funciona, pois quando você faz `variavel[] = 'valor';` o valor é adicionado ao final do *array*.

Dependendo da estrutura pretendida, tem uma alternativa ainda mais simples:

```
$tudo = mysqli_fetch_all($procura1);
```

Isto pega todos os resultados de uma vez, sem precisar fazer um *loop* manualmente. Só que neste caso, vai receber um *array* de *arrays* e não de valores.

Se estiver com PHP 5.5 ou maior, pode usar o `fetch_all` assim:

```
$tudo   = mysqli_fetch_all($procura1, MYSQLI_ASSOC);   // Pegamos todas as linhas
$postos = array_column($tudo, 'posto');                // extraimos só a coluna 'posto'
```

O `MYSQLI_ASSOC` é para que as colunas venham indexadas com nomes, em vez de números. Se usássemos `MYSQLI_NUM` seria necessário `array_column($tudo, numero_da_coluna)`, o que complica um pouco a manutenção caso seja mudado algo no `SELECT`.

Mais detalhes no manual:

> http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php

> http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-column.php

Answer (score 1):

Para isso você poder fazer o uso dos [laços de repetição](http://blog.thiagobelem.net/for-foreach-e-while-repeticoes-e-lacos-no-php) do php.

> Exemplo com o While

```
while($vetor = mysqli_fetch_array($procura1)){
   echo $vetor["posto"] . '<br/>';
}
```

> Exemplo com o For

```
$dados = mysqli_fetch_array($procura1)
for($i = 0; $i < count($dados); $i++){
   echo $dados[$i]["posto"] . '<br/>';
}
```

> Exemplo com o Foreach

```
$dados = mysqli_fetch_array($procura1)
foreach($dados as $dado){
   echo $dado["posto"] . '<br/>';
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Gonçalo, podes fazer da seguinte forma:

```
$contador = 0;
while($array1 = mysqli_fetch_array($procura1)){

$postos[$contador] = $array1["posto"];

$contador++;
}
```

Comment: Obrigado Gonçalo!

Comment: Gonçalo, é legal você querer ajudar o Gonçalo, mas seu código pode ser simplificado assim, em apenas uma linha: `while($array1 = mysqli_fetch_array($procura1)) $postos[] = $array1['posto'];` sem contador. Colchetes vazios em PHP significa adicionar ao final do array. PS: Os negativos não são meus, apesar de não ser uma solução muito elegante, não está errada. E é importante você saber que existe também o `mysqli_fetch_all();` se quiser pegar tudo de uma vez sem precisar do `while`. Segue manual: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php

Comment: Obrigado Gonçalo e Bacco, vou tentar usar a sua solução Bacco. Parece bem mais simples.